# How to run particular code fragment during debug in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I used before Rider Jet Brains. And this IDE has a great feature: I can start debug, and run any code fragment on a special window during the debug session. It's very convenient for small tests during the debug session. I just need to press `alt` + `F8` to start this. But what about Visual Studio? Has it something like this?

Here I will pin an example. Not from Rider but from PhpStorm, but it's not important for this case. All IDEs from Jet Brains can call this pop-up during debug session.

[image]

As you can see, I can run any expression in the Expression input and see the result below.

Has Visual Studio something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2019) exactly for that. It allows to debug and evaluate expressions, execute statements, and print variable values. To display the Immediate window, choose Debug > Windows > Immediate or press Ctrl+Alt+I.

To see the result of an expression, type a ? character followed by the expression, e.g.:

```
?1+1
```

Comment: Thank you! I would like to add one more thing. To call a window like I have described, you have to press Shift + F9. So, Visual Studio has absolutly the same pop-up like Jet Brains's IDEs.  About `Immediate window` - works perfect. Thank you!